# Directive, link function doesn't fire when loading in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, directive

I try to load "emailTemplatebuilder" directive to be used in "emailtemplatebuilderController" controller.

The controller code :

```
'use strict';

define('emailtemplatebuilderController', ['app', 'emailTemplatebuilder', 'servicebase', ], function (app, emailTemplatebuilder, servicebase) {
app.lazy.controller('emailtemplatebuilderController', [
    "$scope", '$routeParams', "$cookies", 'sharedServices', 'servicebase', '$location', function ($scope, $routeParams, $cookies, sharedServices, servicebase, $location) {

        debugger;



    }]);
});
```

and the directive :

```
'use strict';

define('emailTemplatebuilder', ['app'], function (app) {
debugger;
app.directive('templatedirective', ['$rootScope',  function (rootscope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {

            debugger;

        }
    }
}]);
});
```

In this case the link function doesn't fire . But when I load the directive in require part in requirejs config file as below :

```
require.config({
baseUrl: window.baseUrl, //'/app',
urlArgs: 'v=1.0',
skipDataMain: true,

paths: {
...
},
 shim: {
    ...
},
require(
[
'jquery', 'jqueryUi',
'angular', 'angularAnimate',
'angularUiBootstrap',
'app',
'emailTemplatebuilder'
],
function (PNotify) {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);

});
```

and the directive :

```
'use strict';

define('emailtemplatebuilderController', ['app', 'servicebase', ], function (app,  servicebase) {
app.lazy.controller('emailtemplatebuilderController', [
    "$scope", '$routeParams', "$cookies", 'sharedServices', 'servicebase', '$location', function ($scope, $routeParams, $cookies, sharedServices, servicebase, $location) {

        debugger;

    }]);
});
```

then it works. What is wrong with the first case ?

Update :

The way I use in html

```
<div ng-controller="emailtemplatebuilderController">
<div templatedirective></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show how you use your directive. Post HTML.

Comment: Your browser is probably interpreting it as an attribute.  Use camel case in the directive declaration, and then hypened in the html (templatedDirective and templated-directive respectively)

Comment: #dfsq question update

Comment: #Vizkos I did it but doesn't work

Comment: You're not posting all the relevant code. But most likely the app is bootstrapped before lazy-loaded components are defined.

Comment: #estus , Yes the app is bootstrapped .